# Using pyproject.toml with flexible version from datetime

Tags: python, pip, setup.py, pyproject.toml

We version all our company packages with a simple datetime version. Now we are considering moving to `pyproject.toml` instead of `setup.py`. Is it possible to do flexible versioning there as well?

```py
version = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y.%m.%d.%H%M')

# Actual setup
setup(
    name="some-package",
    version=version,
    description='Some description',
    packages=find_namespace_packages(where='src', include=['company.project.*']),
    package_dir={'': 'src'},
    python_requires='>=3.6',
    install_requires=[  
        'numpy',
        'numba'
    ],
)
```

What syntax do I need to adjust the versioning in the pyproject.toml? This one is using `poetry` but there is no need for that.

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "some-package"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
readme = "README.md"
```

Comment: An idea would be to use jinja2 templating and during the packaging stage apply any variables.

Comment: i hve no prior experience with poetry, but have a look at this thread on github: https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/144

Answer (score 9):

Poetry does not seem to support that, see [issue #4299](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/4299) for example.

But [Flit](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/key_projects/#flit) does. Flit allows us to declare the version as "dynamic" in `pyproject.toml`:

```
[project]
name = 'some_package'
dynamic = ['version']
description = 'Description of the package.'

[build-system]
requires = ['flit_core>=3.2,<4']
build-backend = 'flit_core.buildapi'
```

The version is then determined by the package's `__version__` attribute. For example, `__init__.py` could contain this:

```py
import datetime
__version__ = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y.%m.%d.%H%M')
```

Note, however, that in your specific case, when building the package with `flit build`, Flit will observe that the version number does not comply with [PEP 440](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440) and [normalize](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#integer-normalization) it accordingly, i.e. remove leading zeros from day and month numbers.

Comment: In a namespace package I don't use `__init__.py` as it can make them unworkable (if two init's end up at the same level). Is there any other place to put this?

Comment: Sorry, I did not realize your question was specific to namespace packages. I do not know if and how it works then.

Comment: Note also that inspecting your package's version at runtime will then not reflect the actual package version.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up bumping the version before building:

```
python -c "import datetime; print(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y.%m.%d.%H%M'), end='')" | xargs -t -I {} poetry version {}
poetry build
```